# Avoid closing the modal when refreshing the parent page

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, modal-dialog

My website is just like twitter, i am using basic html, PHP, sql query and java script. I have this meta tag  to automatically refresh my page (for post purpose) but when i open one of my modal then the page refresh, the modal is closing. Is there any way or code to avoid it? I want to view info from my modal and the parent page still refresh even my modal is open. Pleeeeaaassseeee help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider changing your design.  Either get rid of the automatic refresh, and instead use AJAX calls to update your page.  Here is a page showing the basics of AJAX: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

You can setup your page to automatically load the modal on refresh.  But I got a feeling that you are probably having people type into that box, so the content would be lost.  Which isn't a good user experience.

For a low tech solution, you could just pop up a small window for post submission using Javascript.  That would decouple your writing from your reading, and you can refresh the other page however you want.

Simple code to pop up a new window is:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('postpage.php','Write New Post','width=800,height=600,toolbar=no');">Post a Message</a>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

You would just need to move your posting code to postpage.php instead of having it on whatever page you currently have it on.